# How do I create a sklearn.datasets.base.Bunch object in scikit-learn from my own data?

Tags: scikit-learn, scikits

In most of the Scikit-learn algorithms, the data must be loaded as a Bunch object. For many example in the tutorial load_files() or other functions are used to populate the Bunch object. Functions like load_files() expect data to be present in certain format, but I have data stored in a different format, namely a CSV file with strings for each field.

How do I parse this and load data in the Bunch object format?

Comment: To be sure: none of the algorithms load `Bunch` objects. The example scripts use those, but the algorithms all want arrays or sparse matrices.

Comment: @Blake, the fit method of the classifier takes in a couple of list objects - list of data (`Bunch.data`) followed by a list of target(`Bunch.target`) - `clf.fit(<list>, <list>)`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't have to create Bunch objects. They are just useful for loading the internal sample datasets of scikit-learn.

You can directly feed a list of Python strings to your vectorizer object.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any utility function to load .CSV? Have a csv with for columns (all strings). Right now i am using python csv reader http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: I would recommend pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/ you need to convert the pandas.DataFrame to an np array before feeding it to sklearn, though.

Answer (score 24):

You can do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.datasets

examples = []
examples.append('some text')
examples.append('another example text')
examples.append('example 3')

target = np.zeros((3,), dtype=np.int64)
target[0] = 0
target[1] = 1
target[2] = 0
dataset = sklearn.datasets.base.Bunch(data=examples, target=target)
```

Comment: @MachineEpsilon The question shows a misunderstanding in how you feed data to a  classifier in `scikit-learn`, so even though this answers the literal question, it doesn't clear up the original misunderstanding.

This link makes it pretty clear: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-create-a-bunch-object

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of [Breast Cancer Wisconsin (Diagnostic) Data Set](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/breast-cancer-wisconsin-data), you can find the CSV file in Kaggle:

1. From column 2 at 32 in the CSV file are `X_train` and `X_test` data @`usecols=range(2,32)` this is stored in the Bunch
   Object key named `data`

   ```py
   from numpy import genfromtxt
   data = genfromtxt("YOUR DATA DIRECTORY", delimiter=',', skip_header=1,  usecols=range(2,32))
   ```
2. I am interested in the column data B (column 1 in Numpy Array @`usecols=(1)`) in the CSV file because it is the output of `y_train` and `y_test` and is stored in the Bunch Object Key named: `target`

   ```py
   import pandas as pd
   target = genfromtxt("YOUR DATA DIRECTORY", delimiter=',', skip_header=1, usecols=(1), dtype=str)
   ```

   There are some tricks to transform the target like it has in sklearn, of course it can be made in a unique variable `target, target1, ...` is separated only to explain what I did.
3. First transform the numpy into a Panda

   ```py
   target2 = pd.Series(target)
   ```
4. It's for use the rank function, you could skip the step number 5

   ```py
   target3 = target2.rank(method='dense', axis=0)
   ```
5. This is only for transform the target in 0 or 1 like the example in the Book

   ```py
   target4 = (target3 % 2 == 0) * 1
   ```
6. Got values into numpy

   ```py
   target5 = target4.values
   ```

Here I copied Hugh Perkins's solution:

```py
import sklearn
dataset = sklearn.datasets.base.Bunch(data=data, target=target5)
```