# How to load my dataset into a Bunch data item

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I can load the iris dataset, etc.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
```

How do I load my own .csv file into a Bunch object?

Comment: maybe duplication?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023411/how-to-import-csv-data-file-into-scikit-learn

Comment: Not the same. That question, and all the answers, load into a DataFrame rather than a Bunch object.

Comment: Okay, did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485592/how-do-i-create-a-sklearn-datasets-base-bunch-object-in-scikit-learn-from-my-own

Comment: I think that clears it up. I voted to close it. Thank you for the reference. This discussion, to me, calls into question the value of those ubiquitous tutorials that start with the toy datasets in a Bunch format.